# running .jar file in ubuntu

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I am doing a project in NetBeans. I made a .jar file of my project. Then gave clean and build, I can see a .jar file in my mainproject/dist folder.

When I try to open the .jar file with OpenJDKJava 7 Runtime, nothing shows. Can anyone help me with this, why is it being blank? I mean it doesn't run or do anything- no response when I click on use OpenJDKJava 7 runtime.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you run it via the command prompt?

Comment: Does it work when running `java -jar yourjar.jar`?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270172/how-can-i-make-a-jar-file-executable).

Comment: Nothing happens from command line also. I gave this command 
    java -jar "mainproject.jar"

Comment: Quick question, is this a gui app that launches a swing window, or have you just not made an _executable_ jar?

Comment: Justin, this is my college main project- I made that into a jar file by right clicking properties and choosing packaging. Then gave clean and build. .jar file is created successfully. Problem is when I try to run the file (I have already done the step Salah mentioned below). When I choose open with openjdk java it doesnt' do anything. Even from commandline no response.

Comment: ...so, it is, or isn't, a gui app? Any JFrame's or anything like that? I'm not familiar enough with Netbeans to know if it's making an executable jar or just packaging it all into a jar. Does an icon pop up in the Ubuntu bar?

Comment: Justin: no icon pops up. I can just see the .jar file, if I give open with archive manager- it shows all files inside.
Yes, I am using JFrames in my project. It is a GUI app.

Comment: Interesting. I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 and found that with the dock exposed, if you run a GUI app that has a default JFrame position of (0,0), you will not see it (bug with Unity). If you move it a few pixels (with `.setLocation()`) it should show up. You could try hiding your dock and then running your app as well (that's what I'm doing currently). I only noticed on Java 7/8 for both Oracle and OpenJDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Right click on the Jar file
2. Select Properties from the menu.
3. Navigate to the permissions tab.
4. Check the CheckBox **Allow executing file as program**

Comment: I have already done this. 
Is it something to do with my java version? It doesn't get the openjdk when I try to open with it- the screen at that time goes blank with no response.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put this here for others.

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 with Unity and found that with the dock exposed, if you run a GUI app that has a default JFrame position of (0,0), you will not see it. It seems to be a bug with Unity that's understood, but not well documented.

If you move the main JFrame a few pixels (with `.setLocation()`) it should show up. You could try hiding your dock and then running your app as well (that's what I'm doing currently).

This doesn't need to be done with Java 6 (either Oracle or OpenJDK), but it seems it's a problem with Java 7 & 8 (both Oracle and OpenJDK).

Answer (score 0):

Install jarwrapper and you can start the jar file by just entering its name on the command line.

```
sudo apt-get install jarwrapper
```